# Replace part of defaultValue string in ARM Template with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, replace, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I need to replace a particular part of the "defaultValue" property in a ARM template file.

I have the following template.json for example:

```
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "workflows_something_company_upsert_name": {
        "defaultValue": "something-company-upsert",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "workflows_something_app_logging_externalid": {
        "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/RessourceGroupXY/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/something-app-logging",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "connections_commondataservice_1_externalid": {
        "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/RessourceGroupXY/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/commondataservice-1",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "connections_sql_1_externalid": {
        "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/RessourceGroupXY/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql-1",
        "type": "String"
    }
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows",
...
...
...
...
```

What I need to achieve is to change the value of "defaultValue":

```
"defaultValue": "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/RessourceGroupXY/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/something-app-logging",
```

to this:

```
"defaultValue": "[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Logic/workflows/something-app-logging')]",
```

Unfortunately I'm not the PowerShell crack so I hope somebody can give me advice which would be higly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by my own:

```
$jsonData = (Get-Content $file.FullName  -Raw) -replace 0x10, (0x13,0x10)
$jsonData = $jsonData -replace '\s',''
$jsonData = [string]::join("",($jsonData.Split("`n")))

$jsonObject = $jsonData | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach($element in $jsonObject.parameters.PSObject.Properties) {

    $found = $element.value.defaultValue -match '(\{){0,1}[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}(\}){0,1}'
    
    if(!$found) {
        continue
    }
    
    $workingString = $element.value.defaultValue
    $startIndex = $workingString.IndexOf('/providers')
    $endPath = $workingString.Substring($start, $workingString.Length - $length)
    $element.Value.defaultValue = '[concat(resourceGroup().id, ' + $endPath + ')]'
}
```